# AfterMap with IMappingAction and IHttpContextAccessor throwing error

Tags: automapper

I have followed the example found [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/docs/Before-and-after-map-actions.md).  I have a class as follows:

```
public class FileServiceRequestMappingAction : IMappingAction
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

```
    public FileServiceRequestMappingAction(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void Process(FileServiceRequest source, FileSearchRequest destination)
    {
        try
        {
            destination.Filter = "somevalue";

            var storageType = "somestoragetype";

            if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.ToLower().Contains("/patha/"))
            {
                storageType = "someothertypeofstorage";
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(destination.Filter))
            {
                destination.Filter += $" and storageType eq {storageType}";
            }
            else
            {
                destination.Filter += $"storageType eq {storageType}";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new TranslationException($"Error in filter. {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

```

In my startup I have:

`services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(FileServiceRequestMappingAction).Assembly);`

When I fire up the app and execute my api query where the map is called, I get the following error:

   `` at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at AutoMapper.Configuration.MappingExpression`2.<>c__60`1.<AfterMap>g__AfterFunction|60_0(TSource src, TDestination dest, ResolutionContext ctxt) in C:\projects\automapper\src\AutoMapper\Configuration\MappingExpression.cs:line 450
   at lambda_method(Closure , FileServiceRequest , FileSearchRequest , ResolutionContext )
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object , ResolutionContext )
   at AutoMapper.Mapper.AutoMapper.IMapper.Map[TDestination](Object source) in C:\projects\automapper\src\AutoMapper\Mapper.cs:line 207 ``

The error message is:

`No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`

I am sure I'm doing something wrong.  Note that in the startup.cs file, I have tried services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup).Assembly); as well.  It doesn't work either.

Any thoughts, anyone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just FYI: I fixed this by switching to using a Profile instead of a direct map.